# How can I gain more energy?

Tags: moonstone-island

The newest [patch notes](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1658150/view/3714963077090076229?l=english) came out, and one line mentions:

> We capped your energy at 99 (sorry if this breaks your OP strats)

While looking through all the spirits owned, I can't find anything would allow me to gain more energy, does anyone know how this is done? Is there a spirit I am missing, or some other effect?